# json_encode not returning anything when statement is true

Tags: php, json, file

I have this php script that will only check if file exists in the server.

```
<?php
$CSVpath = 'http://10.169.00.00:6000/'.$_REQUEST["id_number"].'.csv';

$FinalData = [ 'exists' =>
  (fopen($CSVpath,"r"))
];
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($FinalData);

?>
```

It works and return `{"exists":false}` when data is not exists.

But when the file exists in doesn't show anything.

What's wrong with my script?

Comment: Hi, perhaps `is_readable($path)` would be of help?

Comment: @IronMan still doesn't returning anything.

Comment: `fopen()` returns a resource. Why are you trying to encode that as JSON? What do you expect that to return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fopen()` returns a resource. There's no JSON encoding of a resource, since it has no meaning outside the PHP process that created it.

You can convert any value to the corresponding boolean with `!!`.
`

```
$FinalData = [ 'exists' =>
  !!fopen($CSVpath,"r")
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use curl like the following?

```
$FinalData = [ 'exists' => false ];

$CSVpath = 'http://10.169.00.00:6000/'.$_REQUEST["id_number"].'.csv';

$ch = curl_init($CSVpath);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); # handles 301/2 redirects
curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
$FinalData['exists'] =  $httpCode == 200;

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($FinalData);
```